# android ListView onClick get JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a ListView inflated by JSONObjects. It's working fine for `list.setOnItemClickListener`.
I added up the search facility using EditText and on runtime it searches the Items in JSONArray (containing JSONObjects).
But after searching, when I click on the ListView item, it shows me the original position in JSONArray.
For example, if I have a ListView of these items.

```
Africa
Asia
Europe
North America
South America
```

[positions of items in ListView are from 0 - 4, i.e., Africa=0, South America=4]

Now, if I use EditText Field for Search bar, and type `America` in it, It will now show me the listview having 2 items.

```
North America
South America
```

Now the ListView has two items on run time, if I click on `North America` It would show me the position [0] of JSONArray, which is originally `Africa`, So, instead of showing me Information/Data about `North America` it shows me I clicked on `Africa`

How can I get the JSONObject out of ListView Click but position-id ?

/* Populating ListView onCreate() */

```
public void populateCityList() {
    List<CityRowItem> rowItems;
    rowItems = new ArrayList<CityRowItem>();
    try {
        jArray = readJSONFile();
        if (jArray != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject j1 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                CityRowItem item = new CityRowItem(R.drawable.grain,
                        j1.getString("city_name_eng"),
                        j1.getString("city_name_alias"), R.drawable.city);
                rowItems.add(item);
            }

            CityListAdapter myadapter = new CityListAdapter(
                    GetCityManual.this, R.layout.list_item_city, rowItems);
            list.setAdapter(null);
            list.setAdapter(myadapter);
                    }
    }
    catch (JSONException) {
        ;
    }
}
```

/* This is onClick Listener */

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        try {
            JSONObject j1 = jArray.getJSONObject(position);                 
            String CityName = jsonObj.getString("city_name_eng");
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(GetCityManual.this,
                    GetCategory.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("objCity", CityName);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        { 
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

/* This piece of code reflects the functionality of Searching using EditText */

```
txtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        List<CityRowItem> rowItems;
        rowItems = new ArrayList<CityRowItem>();
        if (jArray != null) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject j1 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (j1.getString("city_name_eng").toLowerCase()
                            .contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        CityRowItem item = new CityRowItem(
                                R.drawable.grain, j1
                                        .getString("city_name_eng"), j1
                                        .getString("city_name_alias"),R.drawable.city);
                        rowItems.add(item);
                    }
                    CityListAdapter myadapter = new CityListAdapter(
                            GetCityManual.this,
                            R.layout.list_item_city, rowItems);
                    list.setAdapter(null);
                    list.setAdapter(myadapter);
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception _e) {
                ;
            }
}
}
```

Comment: Hope you'd feel better now :)

Comment: I think you should let us see more code.

Comment: Code is there.
Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LIst delievers you selected position from actual list adapter, you changed your 
list adapter, so you get numbers from there.   You shall keep priginal positions somewhere
else

Answer (score 0):

Your onItemClick shows you the current position of the list you clicked.
You can have a `List<CityRowItem> CurrentRowItems;` in your class and at init and on afterTextChanged keep a reference to that list  `this.CurrentRowItems = rowItems;` . 
When on click event occurs just `CityRowItem city = this.CurrentRowItems.get(position);`.
Also I suggest decoding the json file only once and then working on with the list.

Comment: Thanks. But onClick, I have to pass the JSONObject to the Intent. How would I do it with CityRowItem city ?

Comment: well then just add the i variable from the for where you're parsing to the list so that when you have a click you get CityRowItem city = this.CurrentRowItems.get(position); and then send the JSONObject of the jArray.getJSONObject(city.i);.

Comment: how about `TextView checkTV = (TextView) list.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.cityTitle);` ? 

I am still getting NullException.
If I can get the Text of that specific clicked item, I can perform searching then too.

Comment: well then you should try TextView checkTV = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.cityTitle); Where view is your clicked view sent in the callback